# Adjust page size to map size automatically in QGIS print composer

Tags: qgis, print-composer, print-templates

I'm looking for a stable way to create a print composer template which automatically adjust its size to the area of interest (defined by a layer "perimeter" containing one polygon feature) at fixed scale 1:25'000.

I tried using the Atlas tools and set it to fixed scale. This works, but it's not stable and difficult to handle with different projects (different perimeter layers).

It most often does not render the map when Atlas is set to fixed scale in "controlled by Atlas", which means changing to "margin around feature". Further, it always kicks my preset scale and uses "nan", and I haven't found the logic to recreate it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Out of curiosity: Why are you using a fixed scale for different AOI? How different are your AOI?

Comment: These are for older QGIS version so you may have to adapt the syntax but the general idea should greatly help you https://gisunchained.wordpress.com/2014/11/09/series-de-mapas-com-formatos-multiplos-em-qgis-2-6-parte-1-multiple-format-map-series-using-qgis-2-6-part-1/, https://gisunchained.wordpress.com/2014/11/18/multiple-format-map-series-using-qgis-2-6-part-2/, https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/automating_map_creation.html

Comment: @erik What is AOI? We need to deilver maps in 10k or 25k scale and therefore adjust the paper size.

Comment: @erik Area of Interest I got it...every project has one AOI as defined through the perimeter polygon and the maps need to be in 10k and 25k...

Comment: @J.R thx, that's the expression I used to create the composition size.

Comment: @Kevkev770 if your AOI is larger than your sheet size, you usually split the area in several parts. Adjusting the sheet size may become complicated, when printing the maps later.

Comment: @erik I know. we print up to 1.5m 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a fixed scale for your project just going to Project Proprieties > General and add your scale (1:25000) to the Project Predefinited Scales. Leave this as only scale. 
Now your Atlas, when you select the option Fixed Scale, your map will use just this scale.

Alternatively, still in Project Proprieties, in *Variables*, you can create a new variable for the project (click in the green plus in the bottom): call it, e.g., *print_scale* and give '25000' as data. 
Now, in the Print Composer, in the Map Item proprieties, where is requested the scale, select the symbol in the right to open the Variables popup > go to *Variables...* and you should see here the variable *print_scale* that you have created. Select it. Now your Atlas will use only this fixed scale for all the pages.

Comment: thx for that. the first option: Is this way possible with two predefinited scales like 10k and 25k?

second alternativ: I defined the 25k in the expressions window but it went to "nan"...is this different with variables?

Comment: For the first option: yes, you can add more than one predefined scale. In that case, the map will choose the best scale to show the geometry. Using an Atlas you will see the scale change page to page according to the dimension of the feature of the Coverage Layer.  For the second option: weirdly, your result is NaN. Can I ask you how are you writing the scale? As a real number?

Comment: I'll try. second option I tried writing the scale directly into the field, via expression and as variable.

Comment: Reading now some of your comments about the need to print alternating 10 and 25K scale, the first option is the one that will suit your request.

Comment: I now created 3 pages, define map size based on scale and use the preset scales to display the maps. this works 75% perfectly :)

Comment: Good to help. If you want we can try to solve the other 25 :).  And if you are happy with my solution please vote my answer.

Comment: I do both. I struggle with assigning the objects (map, title etc) to the pages. if the size changes to much, they switch automatically and position of x/y gets lost.

Comment: You can use the expression options to anchor the objects to a specific point of the page, and make them changing size according with the page size. Check here for some info https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/create_output.html#generate-an-atlas

Comment: oh you are awesome! I assume there is a variable for the page number! awesome!